# Cannot cd into directory even though group has permissions

Tags: command-line, permissions, users, cd-command

I'm aware that there are other similar questions, but nothing in there solved my issue.

```bsh
gitlab-runner@my-machine:~$ groups
gitlab-runner my-user

gitlab-runner@my-machine:~$ sudo ls -l /home
total 16
drwxrwsr-x+ 16 my-user my-user 4096 Feb 13 09:22 my-user
# ... other users' homes omitted ...

gitlab-runner@my-machine:~$ sudo ls -l /home/my-user
total 528
drwsrws---+ 4 my-user my-user 4096 Jun  7  2020 my-dir
# ... irrelevant files omitted ...

gitlab-runner@my-machine:~$ sudo ls -l /home/my-user/my-dir
total 48
drwxrwsr-x+ 7 my-user my-user 4096 Aug 12  2021 my-dir
drwxrwsr-x+ 6 my-user my-user 4096 Jun  7  2020 venv

gitlab-runner@my-machine:~$ cd /home/my-user/my-dir
-bash: cd: /home/my-user/my-dir: Permission denied
```

The user is a member of the group, the group has read and execute permissions on the target folder and the home it's contained in, and yet the user cannot `cd` into it. I have also tried `logout` and then `sudo - gitlab-runner` again, but it still doesn't work. Why?

I'm unsure why the `x` bit shows `s` and I can't find an explanation anywhere. Maybe that's relevant but I don't know what it means nor how to change it, since `sudo chmod g+x` doesn't change it.

Comment: The `s` is the SetUID, SetGID, etc. bit.  You can read about it in many places, such as [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/setuid-setgid-and-sticky-bits-in-linux-file-permissions) link.  As for your problem, why don't you take it a bit at a time?  `cd` into `/home`, then `/home/my-user`, etc.  Let's see where it gets to.  Also, why are you doing `sudo - gitlab-runner`?  Does that user not have a password that you can log in with?

Comment: There is a `+` sign after permissions field shown for each one of the directories, which means that additional permissions are set using ACLs. These may override the "basic" permissions. Check with `sudo getfacl pathname` for each directory. As for the `s` bit on group, it means that the files/subdirs created in directory will have group set to directory's group regardless of who creates them. You can remove this with `sudo chmod g-s pathname`.

Comment: @Ray i meant `su - gitlab-runner`, not `sudo`. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I had ACLs set for that folder, as @raj correctly pointed out in the comments.

I was under the mistaken impression that ACL permissions would be ORed to the permission bits, whereas instead they entirely override them. My ACL for the directory had `rw-` permissions, the `x` bit was missing, and so I had no permissions to `cd` there with that user.